# GADT and explicit forall on ghc 7.8.2

Tags: haskell, ghc, existential-type, gadt

I'm playing with GADTs and explicit forall on ghc 7.8.2. Let's look at the following simple example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}

data T1 a where
   T1 :: (b -> a) -> b -> T1 a

data T2 a where
   T2 :: forall b. (b -> a) -> b -> T2 a
```

Here ghc fails with:

```
Test.hs:7:26: Not in scope: type variable ‘a’
Test.hs:7:35: Not in scope: type variable ‘a’
```

When `T2` is commented out type checking succeeds.
But `T1` and `T2` are seemingly equivalent. Is this a bug in ghc or some limitation of GADTs? If the latter then what is the difference between the two?

Comment: I think this is just about quantification.  The compiler probably has some rule that you either use explicit or implicit quantification, not a mixture of both.

Comment: BTW, the `a` in `data T2 a` does not extend down to the constructors; it's irrelevant what it's named.

Comment: @luqui That's weird. Is there a reason why would `a` be in scope for `T1` but not in scope for `T2`? I just fail to see why explicit quantification should shadow it.

Comment: Why would you expect the `T2` to typecheck? All variables must be quantified. If no variables are quantified, all variables are still implicitly quantified. Think of type signatures with no `forall` as syntactic sugar. Would you expect `f x = x + y` to work if there was no `y` in scope? If you write `T2 :: forall b a. (b -> a) -> b -> T2 a` it will work.

Comment: @projedi, because T1 is using implicit quantification (all variables implicitly forall'd), and T2 is using explicit quantification (and you didn't quantify a)

Comment: @projedi: the `a` in `data T2 a where` is fake.

Comment: @luqui Ah, I see. So `a` in `T1` is not binded at `data T1 a` but implicitly at `T1` constructor. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I originally assumed that `a` in `T1` constructor was binded at `data T1 a` declaration.
But it actually is implicitly quantified in a constructor itself. Therefore `T2` constructor is wrong because it explicitly quantifies `b` and doesn't quantify `a`.

Comment: Indeed. For this reason I sometimes prefer `data T1 :: *->* where` since it does not name its parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with a similar problem. Based on chi's comment, I came up with this solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data T2 :: * -> * where
   T2 :: forall a b. (b -> a) -> b -> T2 a
```

I would rather have preferred the `b` to stand out in comparison to the `a`, but I guess this is still better than an implicit `forall` for those who prefer it explicit, which includes myself.